# Using JQuery and JSON feed how do I wrap my list with <ul> tags?

Tags: jquery, json, flickr

I'm trying to learn how to use JQuery with the Flickr API to create a slideshow of images from a particular set.

I've got the images, and I've got them appearing on the page within the specified div (#images) using the following code:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=XXX&photoset_id=PHOTOSETID&extras=url_s&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", function(data) {
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, photo) {
        var img_src = "http://farm" + photo.farm + ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.server + "/" + photo.id + "_" + photo.secret + "_m.jpg";
        var a_href = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/" + data.photoset.owner + "/" + photo.id + "/";
        var title = photo.title;
        var alt = ' ';
        $("<img/>").attr("src", img_src).attr("alt", alt).attr("title", title).appendTo("#images").wrap("<li><a href='" + a_href + "' title='" + title + "'></a></li>");
    });
});​
```

But the `<li>` need to be inside a `<ul>` within the `<div>` and I can't work out how to do that.

I've seen other suggestions on StackOverflow but when I've tried to apply that to my code I've ended up with several `<ul>`s or the `<li>`s not appearing within the `<ul>`.

Thanks

Comment: You want to be using a template for this...

Comment: Create your <div> and <ul> using HTML! Assign an id to your <ul id="my_ul"> and on $.each function append data to "my_ul"!

Comment: Thank you, that makes me feel stupid because the solution is so obvious!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `wrapAll()` to wrap all the contents within `#images` by any element. Try this.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=XXX&photoset_id=PHOTOSETID&extras=url_s&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", function(data) {
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, photo) {
        var img_src = "http://farm" + photo.farm + ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.server + "/" + photo.id + "_" + photo.secret + "_m.jpg";
        var a_href = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/" + data.photoset.owner + "/" + photo.id + "/";
        var title = photo.title;
        var alt = ' ';
        $("<img/>").attr("src", img_src).attr("alt", alt).attr("title", title).appendTo("#images").wrap("<li><a href='" + a_href + "' title='" + title + "'></a></li>");
    });

    //wrap all the li's within #images by ul tag
    $("#images").children().wrapAll('<ul />');

});​
```

`.wrapAll()` reference - http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

Other alternative is to create `ul` before appending the li's into `#images` and then append all the li's inside the newly created `ul`. Try this.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=XXX&photoset_id=PHOTOSETID&extras=url_s&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", function(data) {
    //Check if ul is present. If not then append a ul into #images
    if($('#images ul').length == 0){
      $('#images').append('<ul />');
    }
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, photo) {
        var img_src = "http://farm" + photo.farm + ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.server + "/" + photo.id + "_" + photo.secret + "_m.jpg";
        var a_href = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/" + data.photoset.owner + "/" + photo.id + "/";
        var title = photo.title;
        var alt = ' ';
        $("<img/>").attr("src", img_src).attr("alt", alt).attr("title", title)
        .wrap("<li><a href='" + a_href + "' title='" + title + "'></a></li>")
        .appendTo("#images ul");//Append the li's into ul
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and I understand a bit more how I should have been approaching it now.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it think you can see that it is obvious that you want to be using a template for this:

Template:

```
<script id="photoTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each photo}}
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/{{../owner}}/{{id}}" title="{{title}}">
            <img src="http://farm{{farm}}.static.flickr.com/{{server}}/{{id}}_{{secret}}_m.jpg" title="{{title}}">
        </a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON( 'your_URL', function ( data ) {   
    $( 'ul', '#images' ).html( photoTemplate( data.photoset ) );
});
```

(You'll need the [handlebars.js](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/archives/master) script to execute this solution.)

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to learn by doing but I wonder whether I ought to learn by starting at the beginning.

Comment: @bmwelby Adding dynamic content to the web-page can be achieved in two ways: (1) by using templates, or (2) by manually concatenating the HTML strings. I think it's quite obvious that templates are far superior. Therefore, I recommend that you learn how to work with templates `:)`